# How to delete all file in firebase folder (ASP .NET)

Tags: asp.net, firebase-storage

I am working on managing image on firebase in ASP .NET. I need to remove all file in folder before uploading file, but I cannot find any way to list all file from firebase folder or delete that folder or delete all file in that folder. I am using FirebaseStorage.net 1.0.3 and after check, I notice that this package has no longer updated since November 26, 2018. My questions are:

- How to remove all file in a folder in firebase in ASP .NET?
- Do I need to remove all file in firebase folder before uploading new file for avoiding redundant file?
- There are any platforms better than firebase for working with image.

Comment: What do you mean by "folder"? Are you using Cloud Storage for Firbase?

Answer (score 0):

It indeed looks like the [step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet) hasn't been updated to add the ability to [list files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files). There's an open [feature request #56](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet/issues/56) for it on the repo, but there has been no traction on that (nor on any other requests in years).

You can either look for a library that *does* wrap the native ability to list files, or you can store the list of files in some additional location that you *can* access. Before Firebase added the ability to list files in storage, I used to keep the list of files in its Realtime Database. On a platform without the ability to list files, that's what I'd still do.